# Windows: How to copy specific subfolders and keep folder structure?

Tags: windows, robocopy, xcopy

I have many sub folders in root folder, they are structured in `year` \ `month` \ `day` way, e.g,

```
root_folder 
    \-A folder
        \--2012            <--- year
            \--01          <--- month
               \--01       <--- day
                ...
            \--02
                ... 
            ... 
            \--12
                ... 
       \--2013
            \--01 
               \--01 
                ...
            ... 
            \--12
                ... 
       ... 
       \--2016
           ... 
    \-B folder
       ...
    \-Z folder
       ...
```

Now, I want copy all specific day of a year to another folder and keep the folder structure. For example, if I want all data in January 1st of every year. The result should be like this:

```
result_folder 
    \-A folder
        \--2012         
            \--01       
               \--01    
       \--2013
            \--01 
               \--01 
       ... 
       \--2016
            \--01 
               \--01 
    \-B folder
        \--2012         
            \--01       
               \--01    
       \--2013
            \--01 
               \--01 
       ... 
       \--2016
            \--01 
               \--01 
    ...
    \-Z folder
       \--2012          
            \--01       
               \--01    
       \--2013
            \--01 
               \--01 
       ... 
       \--2016
            \--01 
               \--01
```

I try to use `robocopy`, but it has only `/XD` switch to exclude folder. What I need is to include specific folder. So how to copy specific sub folders only?